# AngularJS: Limiting Autocomplete AngularJS Results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am currently using:
   https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete github project to create autocomplete for my Angular JS project and it seems to be working except that it displays all the matching results. Does anyone know how to restrict the results to 10 with a "Show more results" option as the last option?

Comment: Have a look at the pull request: https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete/pull/50 You can update autocomplete.js according to the commit for this pull to use the limit attribute.